# Mapped Harddrive, Bitlocker?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, hard-drive, mappeddrive, bitlocker

All the available letters to use for harddrive, i used up.

So for my new harddrive, i used mapping. So i have mapped my new harddrive to a folder.

**My question is, is it possible to still get bitlocker on that drive?**

> If so , how? Or  if not, is there a better way to add new harddrive to
>   my PC when there is no letters left

?

Answer (score 1):

```
manage-bde -on -?

Parameter List:
    Volume      A drive letter followed by a colon, a volume GUID path or
                a mounted volume. Example: "C:",
                \\?\Volume{26a21bda-a627-11d7-9931-806e6f6e6963}\ or
                "C:\MountVolume"
```